# Next.js + Yii2: как правильно сделать структуру?

Tags: reactjs, yii2, nextjs

Всем привет. Хочу спросить вашего мнения, помощи. Хочу сделать проект, где backend на yii2, а frontend на react (next.js).

Я себе придумал такую структуру: backend - папка backend, api - папка api, frontend - папка frontend/web. То есть, я просто все убрал с папки frontend/web и так у меня "живет" next.js.

Насколько правильная такая структура? Может есть инструкция как правильно сделать такую связку?

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: А какая разница, собственно? Где положите, там и будет. Юзеру всё равно не достучаться.

Comment: в отдельный репозиторий будет много правильней, если frontend будет общаться с бэкендом лишь по api